# Word add-in (office-js) - createDocument function not working as expected in Word online

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-app

I have a Word add-in which is trying to use the [createDocument()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.application?view=word-js-preview#createdocument-base64file-) function to create a new document at runtime and then open it. This works fine on Word on the desktop. However, when running in Word online using Google Chrome, a message appears:

> "This add-In is about to create a new document in your default folder
>   on your current cloud repository."

But no document is created. In the Chrome developer console, a message appears:

> "Sorry, something went wrong. Check the
>   OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information."

In other browsers, after receiving this prompt another prompt will appear about the add-in opening a new window, after which the document will appear as expected.

As per the documentation, I'm passing the base64-encoded document to the function. The code in question goes like this:

```
Word.run(async context => {
    var base64doc = fetchBase64(); // gets the base64 encoded document
    const app = context.application; // get the app from the context
    const newDoc = app.createDocument(base64doc);
    newDoc.open();
    await context.sync();
});
```

So my question is: is this a bug in the OfficeJS library, or with Chrome, or is there something else (something undocumented) that I should be doing to make it work properly in this instance?

Comment: I tried this API on OneDrive using Chrome and it's working well. On what host are you calling this API, can you try again?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "what host" - this is in Word online; Office 365. It says new documents are saved to OneDrive; though the actual hostname of a new document ends with "sharepoint.com."

Comment: ok, could you please further try on Chrome the following: don't call the API to create a new document, instead from UI File->New to try whether it succeeds or not.

Comment: When I click File > New in the UI it succeeds and opens a new document.

Comment: Thanks for providing the information, still not sure why it fails, would you please record a video about the repro steps?

Comment: Any way to pass the document name which is opening. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

@msft-jipyua, I'm just a scrub, but can confirm issue here. Image attached is what I see when I call the auto open function from word online in google chrome. Not sure why it isn't working..sorry for non answer, but this was only way i could add to this post

[error message seen javascript console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zqYJ.png)

Comment: Thanks, I am calling this API on OneDrive but can't repro this issue. Would you please provide a repro environment or provide the detailed repro steps? such as the code you are using, the Chrome version you are using and the what kind of doc you are creating?